# Basemap and Fiona won't install for processing of maps & shp files in iPython Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib-basemap, geopandas

I'm a relatively new student of python and am still finding my way
around. I usually find answers pretty quickly via stack overflow but
this one leaves me stumped

I simply cannot get shape and map files to work with ipython notebook.
I can't seem to install basemap or fiona

Here is the command:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiPolygon
from shapely.prepared import prep
from pysal.esda.mapclassify import Natural_Breaks as nb
from descartes import PolygonPatch
import fiona
from itertools import chain
```

And the Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-17f76aeda5fd> in <module>()
      3 from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
      4 from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
----> 5 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
      6 from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiPolygon
      7 from shapely.prepared import prep

ImportError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'
```

I get the similar error for fiona and other components. What am I doing wrong, please?

I've installed matplotlib and other components in the past without issues I've tried using pip commands as so:

```
!conda install basemap
!pip install pyshp 
!pip install fiona
!pip install descartes
```

Output:

```
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
...The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - basemap -> matplotlib
  - basemap -> numpy 1.10*|1.7*|1.8*|1.9*
  - basemap -> python 2.7*
  - conda -> conda-env *|<2.5|>=2.5.0
  - conda -> menuinst
  - conda -> pycosat
  - conda -> python 2.7*
  - conda -> pyyaml
  - conda -> requests
  - conda-env (target=conda-env-2.4.5-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - cycler (target=cycler-0.10.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*|3.4*|3.5*
  - cycler (target=cycler-0.10.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> six
  - matplotlib (target=matplotlib-1.5.1-np110py35_0.tar.bz2) -> numpy 1.10*|1.11*|1.6*|1.7*|1.8*|1.9*
  - matplotlib (target=matplotlib-1.5.1-np110py35_0.tar.bz2) -> pyqt
  - matplotlib (target=matplotlib-1.5.1-np110py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - matplotlib (target=matplotlib-1.5.1-np110py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python-dateutil
  - matplotlib (target=matplotlib-1.5.1-np110py35_0.tar.bz2) -> pytz
  - matplotlib (target=matplotlib-1.5.1-np110py35_0.tar.bz2) -> tk 8.5.*
  - menuinst (target=menuinst-1.3.2-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - mkl-service (target=mkl-service-1.1.2-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - nose (target=nose-1.3.7-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - numexpr (target=numexpr-2.5-np110py35_0.tar.bz2) -> numpy 1.11*|1.6*
  - numexpr (target=numexpr-2.5-np110py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - numpy (target=numpy-1.10.4-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> nose
  - numpy (target=numpy-1.10.4-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*
  - pip (target=pip-8.1.1-py35_1.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*
  - pycosat (target=pycosat-0.6.1-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - pyparsing (target=pyparsing-2.0.3-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - pyqt (target=pyqt-4.11.4-py35_5.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - pyqt (target=pyqt-4.11.4-py35_5.tar.bz2) -> qt >=4.8.6|>=4.8.7
  - pyqt (target=pyqt-4.11.4-py35_5.tar.bz2) -> sip >=4.16.4
  - python 3.5*
  - python-dateutil (target=python-dateutil-2.5.1-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - pytz (target=pytz-2016.2-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - pyyaml (target=pyyaml-3.11-py35_3.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - qt (target=qt-4.8.7-vc14_7.tar.bz2) -> @vc10
  - qt (target=qt-4.8.7-vc14_7.tar.bz2) -> @vc14
  - qt (target=qt-4.8.7-vc14_7.tar.bz2) -> @vc9
  - requests (target=requests-2.9.1-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - scikit-learn (target=scikit-learn-0.17.1-np110py35_0.tar.bz2) -> nose
  - scikit-learn (target=scikit-learn-0.17.1-np110py35_0.tar.bz2) -> numpy 1.11*|1.6*
  - scikit-learn (target=scikit-learn-0.17.1-np110py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - scikit-learn (target=scikit-learn-0.17.1-np110py35_0.tar.bz2) -> scipy
  - scipy (target=scipy-0.17.0-np110py35_0.tar.bz2) -> numpy 1.11*|1.6*
  - scipy (target=scipy-0.17.0-np110py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - setuptools (target=setuptools-20.3-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - sip (target=sip-4.16.9-py35_2.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*|3.4*|3.5*
  - six (target=six-1.10.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - tk (target=tk-8.5.18-vc14_0.tar.bz2) -> @vc10
  - tk (target=tk-8.5.18-vc14_0.tar.bz2) -> @vc14
  - tk (target=tk-8.5.18-vc14_0.tar.bz2) -> @vc9
  - wheel (target=wheel-0.29.0-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyshp in c:\users\i\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting fiona
  Using cached Fiona-1.7.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\i\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-30kz6icw\fiona\setup.py",
line 198, in <module>
        copy_gdalapi_c(gdalversion)
    NameError: name 'gdalversion' is not defined

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\i\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-30kz6icw\fiona\
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): descartes in c:\users\i\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

The version of the notebook server is 4.1.0 and is running on is Python 
3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (32-bit)| (default, Mar  4 2016, 15:28:01) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: hi, I spent quite a bit of time formatting - including quotes for the output and sections for the code, but I kept getting a format error so in the end I just put it all as code and then tried to edit to undo but didn't work.

Comment: Can you try installing from the conda-forge channel? `conda install -c conda-forge pyshp fiona descartes` Using pip to install on windows will not work (you need the correct compilers for that)

Comment: Hi @joris thanks very much - do you mean I type this from the python command line? Sorry about my ignorance. I'm really new to this.

Comment: !pip conda install -c conda-forge pyshp fiona descartes

Comment: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-dpwtsq8i\pyproj\
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
ERROR: unknown command "conda"

Comment: @joris-  thanks, after fumbling around, I figured out that it's just from the cmd view. It is working now...phew! That was confusing but you helped me tremendously. I'm not sure whether a comment can be an answer to a question and you get some points, I've marked it as useful anyway. If you write it as an answer, I will select it. In any case, many thanks!!!

Comment: Indeed, just from the command line! (and without 'pip' at the front) Glad it works now, I will add it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using the [conda-forge channel](https://conda-forge.github.io/) to install those packages with `conda`. On the command line:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyshp fiona descartes
```

Using pip to install on windows will not work (you need the correct compilers for that, unless binary wheels are provided on PyPI, but this is not the case for those packages)

The conda-forge channel is a community led collection of conda packages.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler solution if you don't already have Anaconda installed is to simply install `libgdal-dev` from your system's package manager.  E.g., `sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev`.